# csv import in excel with macro

Tags: vba, csv, import, excel

I want to read out a semicolon (`;`) delimited *.csv file in an Excel sheet with the help of a macro (Visual Basic).

I don't need all data from the *.csv file; I only need three defined columns of it. 
These three columns should be imported in defined columns of the target Excel sheet.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The easiest way would be to import all of it and then copy the concerned columns over to where you want them. Use the macro recorder to learn how to do this.

Comment: Is this a VBA or VBscript question?

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps for this tasks:

1. Loop through all .csv files in your file
   http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/loop-through.htm
2. Look through all spreadsheets in each workbook

   ```
   Dim ws as Worksheet
   Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1) ' Set wb = Workbooks.Open( Your files ) in step 1
   ' Copy columns here
   ```

Finished